# How do I set a background sound on a Web page?

Tags: .net, asp.net

How do I set a background sound on a Web page?

Comment: Please don't. At least, not in a way that doesn't involve an active control that the user can use to disable said background sound.

Comment: that was easy - thanks for the advice.  I won't.  :)

Comment: This question should belong to some web technology tag, lest it be forgotten totaly and never answered. While I agree that it is a bad idea, do you still want to know the answer? In which technology are you coding your webpage on? ASP.Net?

Comment: Leah - yes i am coding on ASP.Net.

Comment: People are telling you "don't" because, in general, background sounds on web pages are unbelievably annoying to pretty much everybody in the world -- but you may have a real business case (a training web page with an audio track that needs to auto-play, etc.) where it's appropriate -- maybe rephrase your question (and tag it ASP.Net) to avoid the negative gut response that most people have and possibly get a real answer.

Answer (score 16):

Don't.

Comment: Sure it is. If you asked a doctor "how can I make it hurt less when I punch myself in the face", their answer is going to be "stop punching yourself in the face, jackass!" Same here.

Comment: Again, not useful. One of my tasks was to implement this, I debated but ultimately I can't tell my boss, who won't tell his client that we're not going to do something.

Comment: Or rather, my boss doesn't care what I think - I see where he's coming from. We're here to make money and keep the client happy, even if we're doing something stupid. If it was my business I would have put more effort into explaining to the client why we shouldn't do that but ultimately if you're going to lose out on $5000 or so because you didn't want to put a background sound on a website *that's* stupid.

Comment: People seem to instantly just jump to the conclusion this is for a site they have more control over - don't assume :)

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to put a background sound you can use [this](http://www.premiumbeat.com/flash_resources/free_flash_music_player/#loopPlayers)
but the sound which play on the opening of the site usually makes visitors angry